# 32feet library application doesn't work on Windows XP, why?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-xp, 32feet

I've written an application using 32feet library. It works on Windows 7,8,10. I can find my device, connect to it, send and receive data, but the application doesn't work on Windows XP. It can't find any bluetooth devices. I need to get it working on XP.

**What could be the reasons for that? Does somebody knows?**

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: I have no error. The application just cann't find any device nearly.

Comment: Alright so the library seems to be working meaning it can access the Windows Bluetooth stack and access your machine's Bluetooth chip. So did you try the discovery scan on Windows XP/7/8/10 from the same place with the same Bluetooth device(s) in range ? Just making sure of a few basic stuff.

Comment: Yes, I used the same Bluetooth device, the same Bluetooth radio and the same distance. I tried it on two different PC with Windows XP and it didn't work.

Comment: Is the Bluetooth chip part of the machine running XP or is it a dongle? Did you try installing & re-installing, checking for drivers ? You may check this guide (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/883259) to try and discover your device with Windows XP "Add Bluetooth Device Wizard". Let me know what happens ;-)

Comment: I use Bluetooth dongle. I tried to reinstall drivers, it didn't help(